# How to install lxml on Python 3.8 using Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I have Python 3.8 and i used command on cmd: py -3.8 -m pip install -r requirements .txt then start to do a lot of stuff until comes something as building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error then some red text then back to white to rolling back and unistall then more red text and then finish. My question its... how i install everything without problems? i have windows 7 and i installed SDK windows 8 from Visual Studio Build Tools. I dont know how copy logs to send info here bc im really noob with that.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from C#? Can you make it clearer in your question how this relates to C#? Thanks.

Comment: im noob and prob im wrong but i installed something called c++ bc was needed to install this but still give me error?

Comment: Note that C# isn't C++, and both the C# and C++ tags are intended for programming questions (i.e. programming with those languages, or related problems). For help with your problem, I'd recommend adding more details. For example: you're getting errors but you haven't included them.

Comment: well its the first time i do this and i dont know how find log where tell u every error on my computer.

Comment: _"then some red text"_ is probably the error message. I think we can both agree that without knowing any details of the problem (other than that you're trying to install lxml and that there's perhaps an issue building a dependency) that it's difficult for us to fully understand your problem because the key details we need are missing.

Comment: i know than red stuff its error but if u tell me where i can find error log i can copy it.

Comment: Why can't you copy the red text? Or at worst, screenshot it? If it's a command prompt you can just select a section with the mouse and hit the enter/return key to copy it to clipboard.

Comment: its so long for this.... i suppose thn the only method its do screen shots,